# "Parse error before "]" token" when assigning to variable[]

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, while-loop

My C program is as follows. It seeks to read a set of values from a file and create a table that produces the average of some floating point numbers.

```
int main(void)
{

    int lake, beach, samples, count, sum;
    float e_coli, ave;
    char recc[20], lakename[20], beachname[20];
    FILE *in;
    sum = 0;
    count = 0;
    in = fopen("july15.data", "r");
    printf("Lake   |   Beach   | Avg E Coli Level |  Reccomendation |\n");
    while (1)
    {
        fscanf(in, "%d, %d, %d", &lake, &beach, &samples);
        count = samples;
        while (count < samples)
        {
            fscanf(in, "%f", e_coli);
            sum = sum + samples;
        }
        ave = sum / samples;
        if (lake == 1)
            lakename[] = "Ontario";
        else if (lake == 2)
            lakename[] = "Erie";
        else if (lake == 3)
            lakename[] = "Huron";
        else if (lake == 4)
            lakename[] = "Muskoka";
        else if (lake == 5)
            lakename[] = "Simcoe";
        if (beach == 100)
            beachname[] = "Kew Beach";
        else if (beach == 101)
            beachname[] = "Sunnyside Beach";
        else if (beach == 102)
            beachname[] = "Sandbanks";
        else if (beach == 201)
            beachname[] = "Port Dover";
        else if (beach == 202)
            beachname[] = "Port Burwell";
        else if (beach == 203)
            beachname[] = "Crystal Beach";
        else if (beach == 301)
            beachname[] = "Goderich";
        else if (beach == 302)
            beachname[] = "Sauble Beach";
        else if (beach == 303)
            beachname[] = "Kincardine";
        else if (beach == 401)
            beachname[] = "Muskoka Beach";
        else if (beach == 501)
            beachname[] = "Sibbald Point";
        if (samples < 3)
            recc[] = "INSUFFICENT DATA";
        else if (samples > 3 && ave < 50)
            recc[] = "OPEN";
        else if (samples > 3 && ave > 50)
            recc[] = "CLOSED";
        printf("%s,      %s,      %f,      %s\n", lakename, beachname, ave, recc);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Unfortunately it produces the error `parse error before "]" token` on lines 22, 32, and 54. Effectively these are the first areas where the string is defined. So line 22 is `lakename[] = "Ontario"` line 32 is `beachname[] = "Kew Beach"` and line 54 is `recc[] = "INSUFFICIENT DATA"`.

I've tried inserting the number of spaces into the `[]` (i.e. `lakename[9] = "Ontario"`) but then I get a subsequent error `"assignment makes integer from pointer without cast"`.

Comment: To copy/concatenate C-"strings" use `strcpy()` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncpy.3.html) or `strcat()`: (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html).

Comment: Also please properly indent your code.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not assignable in C.

The valid assignment/initialization is

```
char lakename[] = "Ontario";
```

You get error for

```
lakename[9] = "Ontario"
```

because  `lakename[9]` can hold just a character.

Anyways there are other options to copy strings like `strcpy()` and family

Comment: `char lakename[] = "Ontario";` is properly called an "*initialisation*".

Answer (score 2):

I would make some modifications so the code is more readable and alert the user there is no lake or no beach if not supported

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    int lake, beach, samples, count, sum;
    float e_coli, ave;
    char *recc;
    char *lakename;
    char *beachname;
    FILE *in;

    sum = 0;
    count = 0;
    in = fopen ("july15.data", "r");
    printf ("Lake   |   Beach   | Avg E Coli Level |  Reccomendation |\n");

    int iterator;
    char lake_names[6][10]={
        {"Ontario"},
        {"Erie"},
        {"Huron"},
        {"Muskoka"},
        {"Simcoe"},
        {"No lake"},
    };

    int beach_code[12] ={100,101,102,201,202,203,301,302,303,401,501,0};

    char beach_names[12][20]={
        {"Kew Beach"},
        {"Sunnyside Beach"},
        {"Sandbanks"},
        {"Port Dover"},
        {"Port Burwell"},
        {"Crystal Beach"},
        {"Goderich"},
        {"Sauble Beach"},
        {"ncardine"},
        {"Muskoka Beach"},
        {"Sibbald Point"},
        {"No beach"},
    };

    char reccs[3][20]={
        {"INSUFFICENT DATA"},
        {"OPEN"},
        {"CLOSED"},
    };




    while (fscanf (in, "%d, %d, %d", &lake, &beach, &samples) !=  EOF)
    {
        recc=&reccs[0][0];
        lakename=&lake_names[5][0];
        beachname=&beach_names[11][0];

        count = samples;

        while (count < samples)
        {
            fscanf (in, "%f",&e_coli);
            sum = sum + samples;
        }

        ave = sum / samples;

        for(iterator=1;iterator<5;iterator++)
        {
            if(lake==iterator)
                lakename=&lake_names[iterator][0];
        }

        for(iterator=0;iterator<11;iterator++)
        {
            if(beach==beach_code[iterator])
                beachname=&beach_names[iterator][0];
        }

        if (samples < 3)
            recc = &reccs[0][0];
        else if (samples > 3 && ave < 50)
            recc = &reccs[1][0];
        else if (samples > 3 && ave > 50)
            recc = &reccs[2][0];
        printf("%s,      %s,      %f,      %s\n", lakename, beachname, ave, recc);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statements of the form `lakename[] = "Ontario";` or `beachname[] = "Kew Beach";` are not valid C.  Instead use something like `strcncpy(beachname, "Kew Beach", sizeof(beachname)-1);` and somewhere up above do a `beachname[sizeof(beachname)-1] = 0;` for safety. Alternatively, make the variables `char *` and then just assign them as pointers.  In this case, that is more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

This solution should work assuming that your input data looks like sample below.

```
1 101 5 5.2 10.9 20.1 30.56 80.6
1 301 4 50.0 30.3 40.2 20.4
```

Code solution.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void){
    int lake, beach, samples;
    char recc[20], lakename[20], beachname[20];

    FILE *in;
    in = fopen ("july15.data", "r");
    if(in == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    
    printf ("Lake   |   Beach   | Avg E Coli Level |  Reccomendation |\n");

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, in)) != -1) {
        // Count number of spaces
        double sum = 0;
        int tokens = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < len; i++) {
            if (line[i] == ' ') {
                tokens++;
            }
        }
        // Add one extra token
        tokens = tokens + 1;
        if (tokens < 4) {
            continue;
        }

        i = 0;
        // Convert tokens to floats
        double *values = malloc(sizeof(double) * tokens);
        char *token = strtok(line, " ");  
        while (token != NULL) {
            values[i++] = atof(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        lake = values[0];
        beach = values[1];
        samples = values[2];
        for (i = 3; i < tokens; i++) {
            sum = sum + values[i];
        }
        free(values);

        double ave = sum / samples;
        
        if (lake == 1)
            strcpy(lakename, "Ontario");
        else if (lake == 2)
            strcpy(lakename, "Erie");
        else if (lake == 3)
            strcpy(lakename, "Huron");
        else if (lake == 4)
            strcpy(lakename, "Muskoka");
        else if (lake == 5)
            strcpy(lakename, "Simcoe");

        if (beach == 100)
            strcpy(beachname, "Kew Beach");
        else if (beach == 101)
            strcpy(beachname, "Sunnyside Beach");
        else if (beach == 102)
            strcpy(beachname, "Sandbanks");
        else if (beach == 201)
            strcpy(beachname, "Port Dover");
        else if (beach == 202)
            strcpy(beachname, "Port Burwell");
        else if (beach == 203)
            strcpy(beachname, "Crystal Beach");
        else if (beach == 301)
            strcpy(beachname, "Goderich");
        else if (beach == 302)
            strcpy(beachname, "Sauble Beach");
        else if (beach == 303)
            strcpy(beachname, "Kincardine");
        else if (beach == 401)
            strcpy(beachname, "Muskoka Beach");
        else if (beach == 501)
            strcpy(beachname, "Sibbald Point");
        
        if (samples < 3)
            strcpy(recc, "INSUFFICENT DATA");
        else if (samples > 3 && ave < 50)
            strcpy(recc, "OPEN");
        else if (samples > 3 && ave > 50)
            strcpy(recc, "CLOSED");

        printf("%s,      %s,      %f,      %s\n", lakename, beachname, ave, recc);
    }

    free(line);
    fclose(in);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: The usages of `sizeof` do not make any sense.

Comment: Still this makes no sense, as the 3rd parameter to `strncpy()` should be used to protect, not overflow the destination buffer, like this (assuming `dst` to be an array of `char` and not just a pointer) `memset(dst, 0, sizeof dst); strncpy(dst, src, sizeof dst -1);` For your reference: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncpy.3.html

Comment: Heh, you are absolutely right. I should've paid more attention to this. I changed strncpy to strcpy and assumed that buffer can always fit the copied string. Thanks again!

Comment: Alright, Thanks guys. But the input data doesn't look like that. Instead it is in one line. Here's the first line:

4 401 4 30.3 50.4 50.5 60.6   where 4 is the lake, 401 is the beach, 4 is the number of samples and the remaining 4 floating point numbers are the ecoli readings...

Comment: How does it look like?

Comment: 4 401 4 30.3 50.4 50.5 60.6

Comment: Just like that with different numbers for 9 more lines

Comment: @Boris please add some context to your post. Just saying "This shoulod work" is not sufficient, when OP shows a clear lack of understanding